# float dashPattern[] = {10, 5};

Tags: objective-c, c, variables, methods

Hopefully someone can help me understand this variable:

```
float dashPattern[] = {10, 5};
```

This is considered a variable? Right?

It does what I want it to but I don't know why. I know it's based on the `UIBezierPath` method:

```
- (void)setLineDash:(const CGFloat *)pattern count:(NSInteger)count phase:(CGFloat)phase
```

This is a method? Correct?

First, I want to be sure I'm referring to code by the correct names so please let me know that I'm calling the above a variable and a method correctly, and if I'm wrong, please correct me.

Second, I've never used [] and {} setting a variable and don't understand what's going on here. I'm still working on getting a solid grasp of some objective-c principles and I want to understand the theory and concept and not just regurgitate code that I've found online.

Comment: Yes.
`float dashPattern[] = {10, 5};` is pure C.  Nothing to do with Objective-C. dasblinkenlight has the full explanation of what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [`dashPattern`] is considered a variable? Right?

`dashPattern` is an array variable. The array has two elements with the values that you provided in the initializer.

> [`setLineDash:count:phase:`] is a method? Correct?

Correct.

> I've never used [] and {} setting a variable and don't understand what's going on here.

The `[]` after a variable's name indicates that the variable is an array with the number of items provided through the initializer. The `{}` encloses the initializer values. The number of array elements will equal the number of values that you supply in the initializer. You can force a different number of elements by specifying the size explicitly, e.g.

```
float dashPattern[3] = {10, 5};
```

in the above case the array will be extended with a third element, even though there are only three values in the initializer.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a very clear and understandable answer. Is there another way to write this? Is there a way I could write this directly for setDashLine: instead of declaring a variable first and then calling the dashPatern variable?

Comment: One other thing... Since, as Steve commented above, this is purely C so does ARC handle memory for this? Would I need to do anything to manage memory? I seem to recall that somewhere in a book that I've read that ARC doesn't handle C content.

Comment: @ShannonBuckland Unfortunately, the `{val1, val2}` syntax can be used only in initializers. There is no "aggregare" syntax for C arrays in Objective C. This is indeed a pure C, so ARC is not managing the memory for the array. If this is a local array variable, the memory is allocated in the "automatic" memory area, i.e. on the CPU stack. It is valid for as long as the function or method containing the declaration is executing. Once the function/method exits, the memory is reclaimed automatically.